# How to read/write extended ASCII characters as a string into ANSI coded text file in java

Tags: java, encryption, arraylist, ascii

This is my **encryption** program. Primarily used to encrypt Files(text)
This part of the program converts `List<Integer>` elements into`byte []` and writes it into a text file. Unfortunately i cannot provide the algorithm.

```
void printit(List<Integer> prnt, File outputFile) throws IOException
{
    StringBuilder building = new StringBuilder(prnt.size());

    for (Integer element : prnt)
 {
     int elmnt = element;
     //building.append(getascii(elmnt));
     building.append((char)elmnt);
 }

    String encryptdtxt=building.toString();
    //System.out.println(encryptdtxt);
    byte [] outputBytes = offo.getBytes();

    FileOutputStream outputStream =new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(outputBytes);


    outputStream.close();

}
```

This is the **decryption** program where the decryption program get input from a .enc file

```
void getfyle(File inputFile) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    String fylenters = new String(inputBytes);
    for (char a:fylenters.toCharArray())
  {
      usertext.add((int)a);
  }
    for (Integer bk : usertext)
  {
      System.out.println(bk);
  }

}
```

Since the methods used here, in my algorithm require `List<Integer>` `byte[]` gets converted to `String` first and then to `List<Integer>`and vice versa.

The elements while writing into a file during encryption do not match the elements read from the .enc file.

Is my method of converting `List<Integer>` to `byte[]` correct??
or is something else wrong? . I do know that java can't print extended ASCII characters so i used this .But, even this failed.It gives a lot of `?`s
Is there a solution??
please help me .. and also how to do it for other formats(.png.mp3....etc)

The format of the encrypted file can be anything (it needn't be .enc)
thanxx

Comment: Since you didn't disclose your encryption method (classical vs. modern) the problem is most likely `String fylenters = new String(inputBytes);`, because characters are not the same thing as bytes.

Comment: i know but how to suucessfully convert bytes into characters without corrupting the string

Comment: Use some kind of encoding like Base64 or Hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **thousands of different 'extended ASCII' codes** and Java supports about a hundred of them, 
but you have to tell it which 'Charset' to use or the default often causes data corruption.

While representing arbitrary "binary" bytes in hex or base64 is common and often necessary,
*IF* the bytes will be stored and/or transmitted in ways that preserve all 256 values, often called **"8-bit clean"**, 
and `File{Input,Output}Stream` does, you **can use "ISO-8859-1"** which maps Java `char` codes 0-255 to and from bytes 0-255 without loss, because Unicode is based partly on 8859-1.

- **on input**, read (into) a `byte[]` and then `new String (bytes, charset)` where charset is either the *name* `"ISO-8859-1"` 
  or the `java.nio.charset.Charset` *object* for that name, available as `java.nio.charset.StandardCharSets.ISO_8859_1`; 
  or create an `InputStreamReader` on a stream reading the bytes from a buffer or directly from the file, using that charset name or object, and read chars and/or a `String` from the `Reader`
- **on output**, use `String.getBytes(charset)` where charset is that charset name or object and write the `byte[]`;
  or create an `OutputStreamWriter` on a stream writing the bytes to a buffer or the file, using that charset name or object, and write chars and/or `String` to the `Writer`

But you **don't actually need** `char` and `String` and `Charset` **at all**. You actually want to write a series of `Integer`s as bytes, and read a series of bytes as `Integer`s. So just do that:

```
void printit(List<Integer> prnt, File outputFile) throws IOException
{
    byte[] outputBytes = new byte[prnt.size()]; int i = 0;
    for (Integer element : prnt) outputBytes[i++] = (byte)element;

    FileOutputStream outputStream =new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(b);
    outputStream.close();
    // or replace the previous three lines by one
    java.nio.file.Files.write (outputFile.toPath(), outputBytes);
}

void getfyle(File inputFile) throws IOException
{
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int)inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    // or replace those four lines with
    byte[] inputBytes = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes (inputFile.toPath());

    for (byte b: inputBytes) System.out.println (b&0xFF);
    // or if you really wanted a list not just a printout
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(inputBytes.length);
    for (byte b: inputBytes) list.add (b&0xFF);
    // return list or store it or whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary data bytes are not all convertible to any character encoding and encryption creates data bytes including all values 0 - 255.

If you must convert the encrypted data to a string format the standard methods are to convert to Base64 or hexadecimal.

Answer (score -1):

In encryption part:

```
 `for (Integer element : prnt)
{
    int elmnt = element;
    //building.append(getascii(elmnt));
    char b = Integer.toString(elmnt).charAt(0);
    building.append(b);
}`
```

-->this will convert int to char like    1 to '1' and 5 to '5'